# Attempts to call a method in the same class not working (java)

Tags: class, methods, types, call

I'm creating a random number generator which then sorts the digits from largest to smallest. Initially it worked but then I changed a few things. As far as I'm aware I undid all the changes (ctrl + z) but now I have errors at the points where i try to call the methods. This is probably a very amateur problem but I haven't found an answer. The error i'm met with is "method in class cannot be applied to given types"

Here's my code:

```
public class RandomMath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bigger = bigger(); /*ERROR HERE*/
        System.out.println(bigger);
    }
    //create method for generating random numbers
    public static int generator(int n){ 
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        //set max int to 10000 as generator works between 0 and n-1
        for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
            n = randomGen.nextInt(10000);
            // exclude 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888, 9999, 0000
            if((n==1111 || n==2222 || n==3333 || n ==4444 || n==5555)
                      ||(n==6666 || n==7777 || n==8888 || n==9999 || n==0000)){
                 i--;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
    //create method for denoting the bigger number
    public static String bigger(int generated){
        generated = generator(); /*ERROR HERE*/
        System.out.println(generated);
        int[] times = new int[10];
        while (generated != 0) {    
            int val = generated % 10;
            times[val]++;
            generated /= 10;
        }
        String  bigger = "";
        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < times[i]; j++) {
                bigger += i;
            }
        }
        return bigger;
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this, Java? Please edit the question and add the language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined a method `bigger()`, only `bigger(int generated)`. Therefore, you must call your `bigger` method with an integer parameter.